# Create a Button Animation in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, xml

I wanted to create a button that changes it's colour when clicked on it . Also the button should pop out a little and then pop back in or bounce .
I already checked out the post related to this but I'm sorry to say that it didn't work out for me.
Also it will be really helpful if you mention the entire part of the code and not the necessary parts. **Thanks a lot in Advance :)**
I can't post the image of the code I typed cos of less reputation . So sorry about that.

Comment: You can't post the image but you **can** post the code you tried. Do it

Comment: It didn't work out for me . Also I am really new to android programming so I really appreciate it if you send the entire code of Java and XML along with layout folder and animation.i learn and understand by looking at them .

Comment: Your message says: "I really appreciate if you do it for me". Learning by example if not bad but it's better to learn by trying

Comment: Sure , I'll try it again but if I see the entire code I will be able to understand which part of the code works for which part .

Answer (score 1):

for just button color change only you can always use Selector drawable as a back ground for example like this!

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="false">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary"></solid>
            <corners android:radius="20dp"></corners>

        </shape>

    </item>

<item android:state_pressed="true">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#000"></solid>
        <corners android:radius="10dp"></corners>

    </shape>



</item>
```

**//--------------------------------------------------------------------------//**

for animation like to raise up you can give a feel of size animation or for free form moving your should use Translate anim

here is the way!

1: put a new res folder called anim and right click on it which will let you make the anim resource and there you make one like "translate_anim.xml" and put this in it

In order to change position of object use  tag. It uses fromXDelta, fromYDelta for X-direction and toXDelta, toYDelta attributes for Y-direction. move.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:fillAfter="true">

   <translate
        android:fromXDelta="0%p"
        android:toXDelta="75%p"
        android:duration="800" />
</set>
```

And then in java you have to go and set up the animation using this

```
Animation translater = AnimUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext,R.anim.translate_anim);

Button btnMoving = findViewbyId(R.id.btn_moving);
btnMoving.startAnimation(btnMoving);
```

here is the resource anim file for scale UP.

```
slide_up.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fillAfter="true" >

    <scale
        android:duration="500"
        android:fromXScale="1.0"
        android:fromYScale="1.0"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
        android:toXScale="1.0"
        android:toYScale="0.0" />

</set>
```